# Spongy Castle AES Android vs Bouncy Castle AES C#

Tags: java, c#, android, encryption

i see this code in android java code project.. :

```
localCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SC");
localCipher.init(2, new SecretKeySpec(arrayOfByte1, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(arrayOfByte2));
byte[] resultarray = new CipherInputStream(cipherDataf, localCipher);
```

The provider is **SC** I refer to the spongycastle libraries :

https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/

I tried to use native AES net 4 and the library C# **BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll** the bouncy castle but do not get the same results in decrypt

http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

**Bouncy Castle code :**

```
KeyParameter key = ParameterUtilities.CreateKeyParameter("AES", arrayOfByte1);
ParametersWithIV withIV = new ParametersWithIV(key, arrayOfByte2);

BufferedCipher c = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
c.Init(false, withIV);
resultArray = c.DoFinal(cipherDataf);
```

**or native code net :**

```
AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
aes.KeySize = 128;
aes.BlockSize = 128;
aes.Key = arrayOfByte1;
aes.IV = arrayOfByte2;

ICryptoTransform ict = aes.CreateDecryptor();
resultArray = ict.TransformFinalBlock(cipherDataf, 0, cipherDataf.Length);
aes.Clear();
```

but I always decrypt fails .. what is the equivalent of c#

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SC");
```

Regards

Comment: `PaddingMode.None` instead of `PaddingMode.Zeros`?

Comment: Same result... i see whit different data in input decrypt fails or in other case I have exception : 
(CryptographicException) - > The input data is not a complete block.

Comment: Did you test it using the SpongyCastle from maven, or some kind of _version_?
I've got the same code in a project which is depending on a kind of modified version of SC, and it doesn't work with it neither.